# How to name LiN(CF2SO3)2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, ionic-compounds, erratum

I found this compound in the list of inorganic lithium salts from this [article on ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/inorganic-lithium-salt).

It is said to be of the sulfonate group. Let's focus on the anion alone.

I'm not sure if it can be bis(difluoromethanesulfonyl)imide because there is already a compound named bis(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide / bistriflimide ($\ce{LiN(CF3SO2)2}$). The structure is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_bis(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide).

I've also seen other compounds like $\ce{LiCF3SO3}$ (lithium trifluoromethanesulfonate / lithium triflate) and $\ce{LiC(SO2CF3)3}$ (lithium tris(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)methide / lithium triflide), but nothing with $\ce{CF2}$.

The sulfonate ions are of the form `R−S(=O)2−O−`, and the sulfonyl group is of the form `R−S(=O)2−R`.

The only ways that make sense to me are `-CF2-(SO2-O)-(O-SO2)-CF2-` and `-SO3-CF2-CF2-SO3-`, both of which seem to form cyclic amides (the two ends connected to `N`). But I'm not sure if such a molecule will be valid or how to name them.

---

Edit: and one more: `CF2=(S=O)-O-N-O-(S=O)=CF2`. But this seems even more weird.

---

Edit 2: I would say, since $\ce{SO3^{2-}}$ is sulfonate, and $\ce{SO2}^2-$ is sulfoxyl, contrary to the Wikipedia page, $\ce{LiN(SO2CF3)3}$ would be lithium tris(trifluoromethane**sulfoxyl**)imide as opposed to lithium tris(trifluoromethane**sulfonyl**)imide.

That would make $\ce{LiN(CF3SO3)3}$ lithium tris(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide. When I Google for it, different sources mention lithium tris(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide as $\ce{LiN(CF3SO3)3}$ or $\ce{LiN(CF3SO2)3}$, but I don't see any other names. This is probably due to the short name lithium bistriflimide / lithium triflimide (Li-TFSI).

Edit 2.1: I forgot that sulfonyl group  was of the form R-SO2-R'. So maybe Lithium tris(trifluoromethane**sulfonyl**)imide is correct.

---

What would be the name of this compound?

Comment: Though not an answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistriflimide#Naming may be of interest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151590/discussion-between-blacklight-mg-and-mithoron).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the answer by @NicolauSakerNeto to my other related question ([Is LiN(CF3SO3)2 is valid, being similar to Lithium Bistriflimide (LiN(CF3SO2)2)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/180858/is-lincf3so32-is-valid-being-similar-to-lithium-bistriflimide-lincf3so22)), it seems that the compound is not as popular is it seems from the papers.

He mentioned that the -O-N-O- bridge appears unstable (although I'm unsure why), and the compound would re-arrange itself into something else, which would make sense for $\ce{LiN(CF3SO2)2}$ to form instead.

He suggested that I check the CAS database, and in it, there are only two compounds with the $\ce{CF3SO3}$ backbone and one reference from an obscure patent, while there were more than 14000 compounds with the $\ce{CF3SO2}$ backbone and over 40000 references.

But checking the CAS database is impractically expensive for anyone who does not have a commercial or academic license, so as it stands, we'll just have to rely one someone else with access to the database to check it for us.

---

**Update:**
I found some compounds with a related structure ($\ce{N(CF3SO3)2}$) by using ChemSpider, with associated CAS numbers, but @NicolauSakerNeto still mentioned that those compounds are suspicious.

But in case the compound was real, it would be named **N,N-Bis(trifluoromethylsulfonyloxy)amide**. Again, this compound may not be a valid one.

Comment: You know, by mentioning you should be careful with deleting, I didn't mean you should undelete it? Well, making this extended comment, that doesn't answer it,also wasn't a good idea :(

Comment: @Mithoron I read about the guidelines and it said deletes count towards mistakes and you should focus on fixing the question. So I thought it'll be best to provide the answer I was expecting to my doubt.